# APDU command change IMSI SIM CARD

Tags: apdu, smartcard-reader

I am trying to use **UPDATE BINARY** command using APDU command for modify IMSI code, but The response is `98 04`.

```
A0 A4 00 00 02 3F 00 -> SELECT MF
A0 A4 00 00 02 7F 20 -> Select DF_GSM
A0 A4 00 00 02 6F 07 ->Select EF_IMSI
A0 D6 00 00 09 [08 79 03 30 60 00 61 33 23] -> UPDATE IMSI FOR RANDOM NUMBER
```

when doing this I get the following response `98 04` and it is not modified.

According to the documentation The response `98 04` can mean the following:

1. access condition not fulfilled
2. unsuccessful CHV verification, at least one attempt left
3. unsuccessful UNBLOCK CHV verification, at least one attempt left
4. authentication failed

How I can change IMSI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From 3GPP-TS-11.011 - You have to verify ADM first in order to update EF_IMSI. See link. Typically only the network has the "password". Otherwise anyone with the password can impersonate the identity of someone else's SIM card.

[EF_IMSI Update Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krJ8R.png)

Answer (score 1):

In order to update IMSI file on SIM , UPDATE command header and data part should be generated according GSM 03.48 specification. For the SIM file structure 31.102 is the specification. 
[image: Command Packet]

Command header parameters should be obtained from SIM vendor. Minimum security Level parameter will definitely enforce encryption and cryptographic cHecksum usage for securing the command data, because real SIM card card manager expects MSL parameters something like that 0x25, so  KiC and KiD key values are required.

Answer (score -1):

You need first to Verify CHV (PIN1 for IMSI).
Use the following APDU and replace your PIN1 value.

```
->   A0 20 00 01 08 31 32 33 34 FF FF FF FF
<-   90 00
```

**Caution**: If you use wrong PIN value, it will be disabled after 3 times.